# Why is list comprehension taking a long time on one machine vs another?

Tags: python, performance, operating-system

Hello and thanks for reading!

**Context**

I have two computers A and B.

Computer A is a Dell Latitude E6230
CPU: i5-3320M @ 2.60GHz
RAM: 8GB DDR3 HD: 320GB Hard Disk Drive OS: 64-bit Windows 10

Computer B is a monster
CPU: i9 7920X 12-core
RAM: 8 x 8GB Geil Evo Potenza RAM
HD: 500GB Solid State Drive Samsung 850 Evo
OS: 64-bit Windows 10 Pro

**The Problem**

For some reason, Computer B is taking much longer to do list comprehension compared to Computer A. I would think Computer B should be faster.

The list comprehension in question is in the [_dict_to_list method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/csv.py#L144) of the python csv module. [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/csv.py#L146) list comprehension takes up most of the time followed by [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/csv.py#L150) list comprehension.

On Computer B these operations take about 95% of the program execution time whereas on Computer A it takes about 30%.

In terms of seconds, on Computer B the _dict_to_list method takes 0.0298408s on average whereas on Computer A it takes 0.00204978s.

I profiled the code using [pprofile](https://github.com/vpelletier/pprofile).

Could it be a missing driver on computer B? Or something  related to the Operating System?

*All suggestions/feedback are appreciated. Thank you!*

Comment: In order to get some proper answers I'd recommend you post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the differences you're claiming. It doesn't need to be real code but code that support what you're talking about. Otherwise answers will be based on pure speculation.

Comment: @BPL the code being run is the same on both machines. Would you like me to provide that?

Comment: That would be helpful.